# How to Split one value from database and display it separately?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a one value from my field in SQL database like this `12345-ABCDE`, I'm having a problem in displaying it in VB.net like this:

- Sales Order No. : `12345`
- Job Order No. : `ABCDE`

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How are you currently getting data? What objects are you using?

Comment: `String.Split` comes to mind.

Comment: @OneFineDay: I'm using datatable and Rows.Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in C#:

```
string xx = "12345-ABCDE";//retrieved field from database
string[] words = xx.Split('-');
string s1 = "Sales Order No. : " + words[0];
string s2 = "Job Order No. : " + words[1];
```

And VB.Net version like this (`xx` is retrieved field from database):

```
Dim xx As String = "12345-ABCDE"
Dim words As String() = xx.Split("-"c)
Dim s1 As String = "Sales Order No. : " & words(0)
Dim s2 As String = "Job Order No. : " & words(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert to string using ToString() method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 ).
Than  String.Split should work.